# Convert TZ data in Excel

Tags: vba

I'm using Excel to display time stamps from a log file.  The time stamps in the raw output of the file is displayed with millisecond precision, which I need to maintain. The time stamps are also in UTC, which I need to convert to my local timezone.  When I use the dateAdd function to convert to my TZ offset, it sets the millisecond value to '000'.

```
GetLocalTimeFromGMT = DateAdd("h", offset, dateToConvert)
```

Is there a way to use dateAdd without losing that precision, or is there another function better suited to the task?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link for more details.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx

```
Function GetLocalTimeFromGMT(Optional GMTTime As Date) As Date
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' GetLocalTimeFromGMT
    ' This returns the Local Time from a GMT time. If GMTTime is present and
    ' greater than 0, it is assumed to be the GMT from which we will calculate
    ' Local Time. If GMTTime is 0 or omitted, it is assumed to be the GMT
    ' time.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim GMT As Date
    Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
    Dim LocalTime As Date

    If StartTime <= 0 Then
        GMT = Now
    Else
        GMT = GMTTime
    End If
    DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)
    LocalTime = GMT - TimeSerial(0, TZI.Bias, 0) + IIf(DST = TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT, TimeSerial(1, 0, 0), 0)
    GetLocalTimeFromGMT = LocalTime

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use Format(YourDate, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000"), but it did not work. I thought DateAdd is definitely the culprit here until I tried to just add 5 hours to a date. When done in the sheet, milliseconds were preserved. When done in VBA, milliseconds were not preserved.  This probably has to do with how Excel treats times and dates. DateAdd, and to an extent VBA, just isn't set up to do it.

The quickest and easiest way is a little dirty, but it works. Put all of your times into a sheet, and simply add 5 hours to them using

```
    ="CellLocationOfGMTDate" + (offset/24)
```

This will give you the times you want and preserve the milliseconds. You can then just pull the times and dates from the sheet.

If you really need to do this in VBA, you will have to figure out how to pull the milliseconds from your date and then add them back after adding the offset. I will try to figure that out and report back later if I find something.